# Can certain values cause Python's csv.DictReader to terminate prematurely

Tags: python, csv

I have a 90,000 line CSV file that I'm trying to parse with Python's `csv` reader, but I'm only getting about 45 lines in before the script terminates. I removed just about everything except some line counting code and I'm left with the following:

```
import csv

with open('list.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
headers = []
i = 1
for row in reader:
    print i
    if not headers:
        headers = list([x.lower() for x in row])
        i += 1
        continue
    i += 1
```

This accurately counts the lines of the dummy CSV files I pass it, but not the real one. Are there values that could be in a CVS file that can cause `DictReader` to terminate?

In the version of this script that actually attempts to parse the file I have to check against `None` before calling functions such as `lower()`, even though I was expecting everything to be string types. Could this be related?

Comment: Unfortunately the csv file I'm working with contains private information, so it cannot be posted.

Comment: Removing the line it stops at gets it to go a little further before it stops again. I'm looking at what these lines have in common. There are about 80 columns so it could take a while. Thanks for the input Celeo

Comment: An interesting problem. Good luck!

Comment: I would assume it gives a traceback of some sort?

Comment: It finishes without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your file in *binary* mode. This is recommended for two reasons:

- In text mode, line separators are translated to the `\n` canonical form, but in CSV columns with embedded newlines the `csv` module can distinguish these from regular line endings because the CSV format uses `\n` for one and `\r\n` for the other.
- In text mode, the Windows file reading routines treat the [0x1A substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z) as an *End of File* character, and pretend there is no more data.

Your CSV file almost certainly contains such a byte, and opening in binary mode will let you bypass Windows' mishandling of that byte:

```
with open('list.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```